# Faulty headphone jack causes applications to do very strange things

Tags: windows-10, audio, hardware-failure, crash

**Some background:**

I have a newish (~1-2 yrs old) Windows PC.
The back panel directly attached to the motherboard works fine, but the front panel seems to have issues. I haven't had many issues with the USB ports, aside from one problem where I have to use the back port to transfer files from my iPhone to the computer. The headphone jack on the front panel, on the other hand, is much more problematic.

I usually have speakers plugged into the back panel of my PC, and headphones plugged into the front panel. At random times, There will be some sort of connection error with my computer and the headphones. While this glitch is occurring, when the volume panel is open (the basic one in the corner on windows 10 which just shows the audio device being used and the volume) I will see the playback device rapidly switch between "speakers" and "headphones" as if the headphones are being disconnected and reconnected about 20 times a second. Eventually This problem will subside, and I can use my computer normally again, until this issue randomly occurs again. It happens infrequently, maybe around once every 2 hours and it happens without fail every time I plug in my headphones.
This issue also happens most times the headphone jack's alignment changes in the plug (i.e when the cord is yanked)

**Here's the interesting part:**
Whenever this happens, Programs on my computer will act in very strange ways:

When I have a video game open, the sound will completely cut out and will not return once the issue is resolved. If I restart the game afterwards, the sound will work normally.
An exception to this is Minecraft. When this bug happens, all sound will cut out just like most other games, however by pressing F3+T Which reloads all sounds and textures, the game will work normally without the need to restart

When I'm watching a YouTube video and this happens The video will crash and give me the message: "Audio render error, please restart your computer". Luckily however, I can simply refresh the page, and the video will work normally again. Any video which is paused will not be affected.

When I'm working in reaper and this happens, The program will go completely unresponsive and continues to stay unresponsive even after the issue is resolved. Luckily, I can still use the bar at the top of the application and go to "file"->"save project". When I restart the application after the issue is resolved, It will work normally again.

Some pieces of software, such as Milkytracker and Sekaiju (the midi editor)(both of which are music sequencing software which have a somewhat dated appearance but still run fine on windows 10) Will outright crash when this happens. However, when I restart them, they work fine.

Most applications will not be affected so long as they aren't playing sound (Chrome, Discord, Steam, most windows applications)

I have never had to restart my computer because of this issue

(Side note: I always restart the program after the issue has stopped and the sound playback device is solidly shown as "Headphones".)

**I am not looking for solutions to this problem. My question Is focused on what exactly is happening, what is causing it, why this glitch messes with my applications in this way, and why it has such different effects on different applications.**

Answer (score 0):

The faulty socket is causing the computer to have to re-enumerate the available audio outputs - many times per second.
This will then need to be communicated to any apps currently using them.

They could all quite probably cope with occasional switching, but you're setting up a race condition where the info is not always going to be up to date, or even necessarily be presented & processed in the correct order. I can imagine they weren't coded to be able to handle this many times in rapid succession. Each crash is different because each is handling it in a different way.

You can usually switch off this smart switching in the sound device's control panel - either that or get the socket replaced & figure out some way to add strain relief to it so you don't break it again.